# Google Drive with Wine

Tags: wine, backup, directory, drive

I tried to install Google Drive Backup and Sync using Wine.

It says "Installation Complete", but since I cannot choose where to install it, now I can't find where it is installed.

Furthermore, if I run the *.exe* installer again, it installs Drive again with no errors (such as "Backup and Sync is already installed" or something like that).

Is it possible that it installed on the Windows partition?
If it was actualy installed on Ubuntu, where can I find it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108036/discussion-on-question-by-foxel-google-drive-with-wine).

Comment: @abu_bua can I keep a folder always on sync using deja dup?